# How do I view data object contents within an npz file?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, object, spyder

I am using Spyder IDE and Python 2.7.

I have a npz file called data.npz which was given to me. I want to load this file into Spyder and view whatever is inside.

To start I've done this:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('data.npz')
```

In my Variable Explorer in Spyder, I have a variable with the name "data" and the type "object". When I double-click on this variable, Spyder gives an error saying "object arrays are currently not supported".

When I just type

```
data
```

I get something like this:

```
array({'a': array([ 1,2,3, ...,
         4,5,6]), 'b': 10, 'c': array([-1,-2,-3]), 'd': 25, 'e': 1}, dtype=object)
```

How do I access 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', etc?

Comment: I've never seen anything like that, but it seems that you have an array containing a dictionary. Regular slicing like `data[0]` does not seem to work on such object. A quick solution would be to convert your array to a dict like so: `dict_data = data.tolist()` and then slice using the key values. In your case `dict_data['a']` will return `array([123,...])` and so on.

Comment: @gionni Awesome, worked perfect thanks.

Comment: You are welcome! ;-)

Comment: Spyder provides Variable Explorer which is somehow very convenient in this case. Let's take the data as in the above question. If anyone works in Eclipse or IPython, `print(data.files)` results in a list `['a','b','c','d','e']`. Then, `data['a']` will return the content of `a` as @gionni presented in the above comment.

Answer (score 5):

to obtain a list of all the constituent files, simply use:

```
$ data.files
```

Answer (score -1):

Try accessing each key in the dictionary as follows:

```
data['a']  
data['b']
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

print(data.files) will give you a list of arrays contained within the npz file. you can then use the data['a'] to view contents of a, and data['b'] to view b, so on and so forth