# Saving in a file an array or DataFrame together with other information

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, stata, hdf5

The statistical software [Stata](https://www.stata.com/) allows short text snippets to be saved within a dataset. This is accomplished either using [`notes`](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/dnotes.pdf) and/or [`characteristics`](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/u12.pdf#u12.8Characteristics).

This is a feature of great value to me as it allows me to save a variety of information, ranging from reminders and to-do lists to information about how I generated the data, or even what the estimation method for a particular variable was.

I am now trying to come up with a similar functionality in Python 3.6. So far, I have looked online and consulted a number of posts, which however do not exactly address what I want to do.

A few reference posts include:

- [best way to preserve numpy arrays on disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619199/best-way-to-preserve-numpy-arrays-on-disk)
- [What is the difference between save a pandas dataframe to pickle and to csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770542/what-is-the-difference-between-save-a-pandas-dataframe-to-pickle-and-to-csv)
- [What is the fastest way to upload a big csv file in notebook to work with python pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010212/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-upload-a-big-csv-file-in-notebook-to-work-with-python)
- [How do I view data object contents within an npz file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289302/how-do-i-view-data-object-contents-within-an-npz-file)

For a small `NumPy` array, I have concluded that a combination of the function [`numpy.savez()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez) and a `dictionary` can store adequately all relevant information in a single file.

For example:

```
a = np.array([[2,4],[6,8],[10,12]])
d = {"first": 1, "second": "two", "third": 3}

np.savez(whatever_name.npz, a=a, d=d)
data = np.load(whatever_name.npz)

arr = data['a']
dic = data['d'].tolist()
```

However, the question remains:

**Are there better ways to potentially incorporate other pieces of information in a file containing  a `NumPy` array or a (large) `Pandas` `DataFrame`?**

I am particularly interested in hearing about the particular *pros* and *cons* of any suggestions you may have with examples. The fewer dependencies, the better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many options. I will discuss only HDF5, because I have experience using this format.

**Advantages**: Portable (can be read outside of Python), native compression, out-of-memory capabilities, metadata support.

**Disadvantages**: Reliance on single low-level C API, possibility of data corruption as a single file, deleting data does not reduce size automatically.

In my experience, for performance and portability, *avoid* `pyTables` / `HDFStore` to store numeric data. You can instead use the intuitive interface provided by [`h5py`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/index.html).

**Store an array**

```
import h5py, numpy as np

arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000, 1000))

f = h5py.File('file.h5', 'w', libver='latest')  # use 'latest' for performance

dset = f.create_dataset('array', shape=(1000, 1000), data=arr, chunks=(100, 100),
                        compression='gzip', compression_opts=9)
```

**Compression & chunking**

There are many compression choices, e.g. `blosc` and `lzf` are good choices for compression and decompression performance respectively. Note `gzip` is native; other compression filters may not ship by default with your HDF5 installation.

Chunking is another option which, when aligned with how you read data out-of-memory, can significantly improve performance.

**Add some attributes**

```
dset.attrs['Description'] = 'Some text snippet'
dset.attrs['RowIndexArray'] = np.arange(1000)
```

**Store a dictionary**

```
for k, v in d.items():
    f.create_dataset('dictgroup/'+str(k), data=v)
```

**Out-of-memory access**

```
dictionary = f['dictgroup']
res = dictionary['my_key']
```

There is no substitute for reading the `h5py` [documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/index.html), which exposes most of the C API, but you should see from the above there is a significant amount of flexibility.

Comment: A few remarks: 1) The blosc will be much faster for compressing data. 2) If Many dsets are created and backwards compability isn't a big issue you f = h5py.File('name.hdf5', libver='latest') can be used. This should improve speed quite a bit (small, but many dsets)

Comment: @max9111, (1) Is `blosc` native / portable outside of Python, e.g. you can view in HDFView / other libraries? (2) Thank you, I'll update with `libver` argument.

Comment: The Blosc-filter can be installed system wide. https://github.com/Blosc/hdf5-blosc I would mention it because it can be a magnitude faster than gzip, but you are right it isn't installed by a default HDF5 installation.

Comment: @max9111 I am not familiar with blosc filter.  Does it just apply some filtering, or is this just a compression library?  In pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf() there is an option for "blosc" under complib (i.e. built in, no need for additional packages), which is just compression.  Same thing?

Comment: Yes it is a package of compression and shuffle filters. For comparison you can try the following example with gzip and compare the performance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672130/saving-to-hdf5-is-very-slow-python-freezing/48997927#48997927 (In this example I used pytables to register the blosc filters, but this should also work with globally installed blosc filters, mentioned in the comment above)

Answer (score 1):

A practical way could be to embed meta-data directly inside the Numpy array. The advantage is that, as you'd like, there's no extra dependency and it's very simple to use in the code.
However, this doesn't fully answers your question, because you still need a mechanism to save the data, and I'd recommend using [jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49991172/3283333)'s solution using HDF5.

To include metadata in an `ndarray`, there is an example in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array). 
You basically have to subclass an `ndarray` and add a field `info` or `metadata` or whatever.

It would give (code from the link above)

```
import numpy as np

class ArrayWithInfo(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        # Input array is an already formed ndarray instance
        # We first cast to be our class type
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        # add the new attribute to the created instance
        obj.info = info
        # Finally, we must return the newly created object:
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        # see InfoArray.__array_finalize__ for comments
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)
```

To save the data through `numpy`, you'd need to overload the `write` function or use another solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question, although very open-ended I think.

**Text Snippets**
For text snippets that have literal notes (as in, not code and not data), I really don't know what your use case is, but I don't see why I would deviate from using the usual `with open() as f: ...`

**Small collections of various data pieces**
Sure, your `npz` works. Actually what you are doing is very similar to creating a dictionary with everything you want to save and pickling that dictionary.

See [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/neps/npy-format.html#rationale) for a discussion of the differences between pickle and npz (but mainly, npz is optimized for numpy arrays).

Personally, I'd say if you are not storing Numpy arrays I would use pickle, and even implement a quick `MyNotes` class that is basically a dictionary to save stuff in it, with some additional functionality you may want.

**Collection of large objects**
For really big np.arrays or dataframes I have used before the HDF5 format. The good thing is that it is already built in into pandas and you can directly [`df.to_hdf5()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-hdf5). It does need underneath `pytables` -installation should be fairly painless with pip or conda- but using pytables directly can be a much bigger pain.

Again, this idea is very similar: you are creating an HDFStore, which is pretty much a big dictionary in which you can store (almost any) objects. The benefit is that the format utilizes space in a smarter way by leveraging repetition of similar values. When I was using it to store some ~2GB dataframes, it was able to reduce it by almost a full order of magnitude (~250MB).

**One last player: `feather`**
[`Feather`](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/03/feather-a-fast-on-disk-format-for-data-frames-for-r-and-python-powered-by-apache-arrow/) is a project created by Wes McKinney and Hadley Wickham on top of the Apache Arrow framework, to persist data in a binary format that is language agnostic (and therefore you can read from R and Python). However, it is still under development, and last time I checked they didn't encourage to use it for long-term storage (since the specification may change in future versions), rather than just use it for communication between R and Python.

They both just launched [Ursalabs](https://ursalabs.org/), literally just weeks ago, that will continue growing this and similar initiatives.

Answer (score 0):

You stated as the reasons for this question:

> ... it allows me to ***save a
>   variety of information, ranging from reminders and to-do lists, to
>   information about how i generated the data, or even what the
>   estimation method for a particular variable was***.

May I suggest a different paradigm than that offered by Stata? The notes and characteristics seem to be very limited and confined to just text. Instead, you should use [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/index.html) for your research and data analysis projects. It provides such a rich environment to document your workflow and capture details, thoughts and ideas as you are doing your analysis and research. It can easily be shared, and it's presentation-ready.

Here is [a gallery of interesting Jupyter Notebooks](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/A-gallery-of-interesting-Jupyter-Notebooks) across many industries and disciplines to showcase the many features and use cases of notebooks. It may expand your horizons beyond trying to devise a way to tag simple snippets of text to your data.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JPP that hdf5 storage is a good option here.  The difference between his solution and mine is mine uses Pandas dataframes instead of numpy arrays.  I prefer the dataframe since this allows mixed types, multi-level indexing (even datetime indexing, which is VERY important for my work), and column labeling, which helps me remember how different datasets are organized.  Also, Pandas provides a slew of built-in functionalities (much like numpy).  Another benefit of using Pandas is it has a hdf creator built in (i.e. pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf), which I find convenient

When storing the dataframe to h5 you have the option of storing a dictionary of metadata as well, which can be your notes to self, or actual metadata that does not need to be stored in the dataframe (I use this for setting flags as well, e.g. {'is_agl': True, 'scale_factor': 100, 'already_corrected': False, etc.}.  In this regard, there is no difference between using a numpy array and a dataframe.  For the full solution see  [my original question and solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129095/save-additional-attributes-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

jpp's answer is pretty comprehensive, just wanted to mention that as of pandas v22 parquet is very convenient and fast option with almost no drawbacks vs csv (accept perhaps the coffee break).

[read parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_parquet.html)

[write parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html)

At time of writing you'll need to also

```
pip install pyarrow
```

In terms of adding information you have the metadata which is attached to the data

```html
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(1000, 10)))

tab = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)

tab = tab.replace_schema_metadata({'here' : 'it is'})

pq.write_table(tab, 'where_is_it.parq')

pq.read_table('where_is_it.parq')
```

which then yield a table

```
Pyarrow table
0: double
1: double
2: double
3: double
4: double
5: double
6: double
7: double
8: double
9: double
__index_level_0__: int64
metadata
--------
{b'here': b'it is'}
```

To get this back to pandas:

```
tab.to_pandas()
```